# 1-Dimensional array -> 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, 2d

So i'm a beginner;
The task is to convert a given string into the array, the string always has the first characcter as the amount of rows and the second character as the amount of columns.

My problem is to solve how to move the rest of the string 's' into the 2D array from the 1D array.

Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Main {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] s = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
        int arows = Integer.parseInt(s[0]);
        int acols = Integer.parseInt(s[1]);


        int[][] cells = new int[arows][acols];

        for (int col = 0; col < acols; col++){
          for (int row = 0; row <= arows;row++){
            cells[row][col] = Integer.parseInt(s[2]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide an example string and how the values aside from the first two which are rows and columns are supposed to be put into the 2d array?

Comment: Sure, "2 3 1 2 3 4 5 6" This is one input, this would make the array look like this if it worked:
1 2 3
4 5 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a counter for your for-loops to iterate through the input string. What you are doing right now is to fill your 2D-Array with the third element of your string.

One solution would be to just declare a variable i = 2, and increment it for each pass of the inner for-loop.

```
int i = 2
for (int col = 0; col < acols; col++){
    for (int row = 0; row < arows;row++){
        cells[row][col] = Integer.parseInt(s[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Edit: removed <= in row loop, changed the initial value of the index to 2

Comment: You're so right! I thought of it, but in another way... I knew i had to increment it somehow, but couldn't figure it out. I first thought of another loop around it, but that wouldn't do the job. Thank you very much!

Comment: `row <= arows` should probably be `row < arows` too.

Comment: Thanks SirRaffleBuffle! Edited

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution, you have to put another iterator, and initialize it to 2, so to skip the first two elements of s[]

```
int i = 2;
for (int col = 0; col < acols; col++){
    for (int row = 0; row < arows;row++){
        cells[row][col] = Integer.parseInt(s[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```